# Use of SharedFlow in Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow, kotlin-sharedflow

Hey I am learning flow in kotlin. I am learning about **MutableStateFlow** and **MutableSharedFlow**. I tried to learn **MutableStateFlow** in real world example. But I am unable to get the **MutableSharedFlow** example, which place it suits more. I tried some **MutableStateFlow**

For example when we are fetching data from api we can use seal class to populate accordingly .

**LoggedState.kt**

```
sealed class LoggedState {
    data class OnSuccess(val data: List<XYZ>) : LoggedState()
    object OnEmpty : LoggedState()
    data class IsLoading(val isLoading: Boolean = true) : LoggedState()
    data class OnError(val message: String) : LoggedState()
}
```

**SettingsViewModel.kt**

```
class SettingsViewModel : ViewModel() {

 var loggedMutableStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<LoggedState>(LoggedState.OnEmpty)

 fun fetchData(){
   val result = dataRepository.getLogged()
                result.handleResult(
                    onSuccess = { response ->
                        val data = response?.items
                        if (!data.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                            loggedMutableStateFlow.value = LoggedState.OnSuccess(data)
                        } else {
                            loggedMutableStateFlow.value = LoggedState.OnEmpty
                        }
                    },
                    onError = {
                        loggedMutableStateFlow.value = LoggedState.OnError(it.message)
                    }
                )
 }

}
```

**Activit.kt**

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED) {
                viewModel.loggedMutableStateFlow.collect { state ->
                    when (state) {
                        is LoggedState.OnEmpty -> {
                           // view gone
                        }
                        is LoggedState.OnSuccess -> {
                            // show ui
                        }
                        is LoggedState.IsLoading -> {
                            // show spinner
                        }
                        is LoggedState.OnError-> {
                            // show error message
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I all get the **MutableStateFlow** example. Can someone guide me how to do [MutableSharedFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow.html) in real world examples. Also I am curious about parameters

1. **replay**
2. **extraBufferCapacity**
3. **onBufferOverflow**

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

#### StateFlow

StateFlow represents a value that changes and you can listen to those changes as a flow. StateFlow is usually used to represent the state of something in your app, like say the text that should be shown in a TextView. StateFlow is similar to [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) in android or [Subjects](https://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) in reactive streams.

#### SharedFlow

SharedFlow represents a stream of values and it can be listened to multiple times just like StateFlow. But it doesn't really have a "current" value (it can have a buffer though). SharedFlow has an arbitrary size buffer that you can configure. SharedFlow is similar to [Processor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Flow.Processor.html) in reactive streams.

##### Why use it?

SharedFlow's use is more general but it can be used for example to represent button touch events. Since since button touches don't have a "current" value and are really just events in time, SharedFlow would be more appropriate. Another example is a stream of audio data going to a speaker.

##### Parameters

`replay` : This is number of events from the buffer the SharedFlow will emit to *new subscribers*.

`extraBufferCapacity` : This is the number of events in the buffer the SharedFlow **will not** emit to new subscribers.

The total buffer size is `replay` + `extraBufferCapacity`. Default is 0 for both. Typically you want one or the other but you can use both.

`onBufferOverflow`: represents what happens when the buffer is full and you try to use `emit`. There are three possible options for [BufferOverflow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-buffer-overflow/index.html):

- `SUSPEND`: This will make emit suspend until there's space in the buffer. This is the default.
- `DROP_LATEST`: This will drop the latest value in the buffer.
- `DROP_OLDEST`: This will drop the oldest value in the buffer.

Since the default buffer is zero and overflow strategy is suspend, emit *will always suspend* with the default parameters.

##### Relationship with StateFlow

StateFlow *is* a SharedFlow but SharedFlow is more general than StateFlow. StateFlow is kind of like a SharedFlow with replay buffer size 1. But with StateFlow you can additionally read and write to that value easily with property accessor syntax like this:

```
stateFlow.value = "hello"
val text = stateFlow.value
```

##### Usage

You listen SharedFlow to the same way you do StateFlow albeit with some caveats when it comes to buffers. To send values to a SharedFlow you can use `emit` from a suspend function or the best effort `tryEmit` from a non suspend function.

Note that `tryEmit` *will never emit a value* with the default parameters since the buffer is zero. It will only really work properly in cases where you know the buffer is non zero and the overflow strategy is not `SUSPEND`.

A reasonable use case for shared flow is to send button presses to a view model like this:

```kotlin
class WeatherViewModel {
    val refreshEvents = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>(
        extraBufferCapacity = 1, 
        onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST
    )
}


fun onButtonPress() {
    refreshEvents.tryEmit(Unit)
}
```

In practice it's probably better to use an intermediate [callbackFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html?query=fun%20%3CT%3E%20callbackFlow(block:%20suspend%20ProducerScope%3CT%3E.()%20-%3E%20Unit):%20Flow%3CT%3E) rather than do it this way.

Comment: `Interface SharedFlow does not have constructors` when trying to use your code example.

Comment: Thank you Akito, that was an error. Fixed by changing to MutableSharedFlow.

Answer (score 4):

`MutableStateFlow` is similar to `MutableLiveData`, both have `.value` to access the value or to change the value.

`MutableSharedFlow` is similar to `SingleLiveEvent`, used for observing **instant-state** changes.

More example and tutorial you can check out this video: https://youtu.be/6Jc6-INantQ

Comment: I tried this video earlier, I want more real example to fit `MutableSharedFlow`

Comment: SharedFlow is only analogous to SingleLiveEvent if you set the `replay` to 0.

Comment: SharedFlow(replay = 0) will continue to emit event, when the UI is in background(ie: when no collector available). So those events will be lost even after UI comes to foreground. 

Here is a reference to use shared flow similar to SingleLiveEvent
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/3002#issue-1038122202